# Running docker build on a dockerfile located within a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm a beginner with Docker and I'm trying to get to grips with its structures and processes. I have the following scenario at work that I'm trying to figure out.

I have a docker container `my-container` running on a node. Inside this container is a Dockerfile, which I've updated with a couple of RUN lines so that it will install something every time the container is run. I removed the existing docker image, and I want to rebuild and tag a docker image using the updated Dockerfile. The Dockerfile edit and image rebuild is only required once.

Is there a best, or generally accepted method of getting `docker build` to run using a Dockerfile that is located within a container? I've searched around and could find a few different methods:

Run `docker build` from within the container, using Docker in Docker as outlined [here](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci)

Run `docker build` from within the container by passing the socket (although this should never be done, is there a way of closing the vulnerability after you've run the command (a once off) and running the container again without the bind mounting using -v?

Run `docker build` from outside the container, but using the url of the container that contains the updated dockerfile as the build context? See:
[3 different ways to provide docker build context](https://blog.codeship.com/3-different-ways-to-provide-docker-build-context/) and [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-url).

Some other method that I haven't managed to find yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define the Dockerfile inside the container as volume and then call that Dockerfile from outside(host) with docker build command. i think its the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Docker image called "Docker in Docker" which lets you call Docker inside the container, maybe that could point some hints in your setup.

https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion - Docker in Docker is one of the methods I'm considering, but it seems to be open to a lot of potential problems.